# How can I easily and cheaply check if text in a note is identical to another note?

Tags: text-editing

I'm more concerned about text since images and video are easily detectable. The only way I know of that I can cheaply but frustratingly do is: Take the latest and last backed-up text, open them both in notepads, keep making one pop up to see "change" visually, erase any new lines from the latest text until there is no change, repeat as you scroll down, then check the text count in a online letter counter. This definitely 100% works, the correct letters and count are checked, but is time consuming and painful. What about saving any edits as two copies and then have a program check if they are exact? That should not be hard to make/get/run.

Comment: Would you be alright with a solution that checks whether the files are exactly identical in every respect? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: sounds like you need a diff tool, however software recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Well, if I edit and save it as two copies and check them then and even way later, that is a start, but that leaves the time when I edit as a possible un-checked flaw. I wonder if only 1 word would change or you would easily see many paragraphs gone or fliped. Currently I use both XP and Windows 10 but will be upgrading my desktop-based computer to a Windows 7. Though that "shouldn't" matter.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm a linux person, so my answer is untested Google-Fu)

```
FC file1 file2
```

will provide you with the differences between 2 text files.  (/B switch does binary)

More Googling found a freeware GUI to do something similar - http://windiff.en.lo4d.com/

Comment: If I can get that program working, then that should be sufficient! Thank you! This will show I presume in color which is identical and which is not (which for these I'll check if they are simply the new latest lines I have added).

Comment: I tried two totally different texts, red and yellow colors were used to highlight different/none/same, yet I added 8 words to a copy of a different text note and it didn't detect it it simply shows alllll white with like jztbg at the top which some of these letters were not even added.